# Open an ICS File in Outlook 2010 with the To: field populated

Tags: windows, outlook, icalendar

When a user click on a room from a intranet site I am going to lauch a dialog to open an ICS file (this will be shipped with my solution - at the start it will be hard coded with a date, Description/location etc) - eventually might do this dynamically from the site.  What I want to get working however is to have it poulate the To: in the meeting request with the room email address, the user can then add other people that need to attend the meeting.  Below is the code for my ics file however it is not working (the To field is not populated with the address).  If i change and put ORGANIZER:meetingroom@mycompany.com - it adds this and I can see all the bookings, etc for the room, however this does not allow me to invite other contacts to the meeting.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;
:MAILTO:meetingroom@mycompany.com
DTSTART:20110928T000000Z
DTEND:20111001T000000Z
SUMMARY:Your Meeting
LOCATION:Meeting Room
DESCRIPTION:Test
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually got this sorted.  For anyone who comes across similar - I went to Outlook 2010 - created a appointment and then saved it as an ics file.  I then opened the file Outlook had saved with Notepad++ so I could view the syntax.  With it I made the adjuctment below to my file and it works fine. :).

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN="Your Meeting Room";CUTYPE=RESOURCE;ROLE=NON-PARTICIPANT;RSV
    P=TRUE:mailto:meetingroom@mycompany.com
DTSTART:20110928T000000Z
DTEND:20111001T000000Z
SUMMARY:Your Subject..
LOCATION:Your Meeting Room 
END:VEVENT
```

END:VCALENDAR